# How do I install a different version of subversion on Lubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, svn

When you install it from

```
apt-get install svn
```

The version is 1.6.17

The version in the Ubuntu repository is 1.7.9, which is what I need. How do I get that version on Lubuntu?

I tried compiling from source, but kept getting error after error after needing a billion dependencies.

Lubuntu:

```
xx@xx-VirtualBox:~$ apt-cache policy subversion
subversion:
  Installed: 1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.3
  Candidate: 1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.3 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ apt-cache policy subversion
subversion:
  Installed: 1.7.9-1+nmu6ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.7.9-1+nmu6ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.7.9-1+nmu6ubuntu3 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think you mean `subversion` - I have updated the question

Comment: But the version in Ubuntu repositories says `1.6.17`.Where is `1.7.9`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm running Lubuntu, and it installs 1.6.17. On my Ubuntu VM, it installs 1.7.9 - I'm trying to find a way to install 1.7.9 on Lubuntu without compiling from source

Comment: But in the Ubuntu VM, it shows the installed version as `Installed: 1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.3`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's the output from Lubuntu VM, not Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want the Saucy version to be installed on a Precise system.

The only possible way to do that is to manually install the corresponding Debian packages:

- [subversion](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/subversion/subversion_1.7.9-1+nmu6ubuntu3_amd64.deb)
- [libsvn1](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/subversion/libsvn1_1.7.9-1+nmu6ubuntu3_amd64.deb)

And from the folder where you downloaded these two files:

```
sudo dpkg -i libsvn1 subversion
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought my Ubuntu VM was on 12.04 as well. I tried your command, but dependencies kept failing as they were the incorrect versions.